# What is the latex code for pentadiagonal system of equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

Can anyone please provide or guide me to write the latex code for the given system of equation?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's quite hard to fit this in a standard line width.

I used a few tricks for minimizing the amount of input:

1. `\w[x]` typesets `\mathbf{w}_{jx}`;
2. `\r[x]` typesets `\mathbf{r}_{jx}`;
3. `\?` is used to push the object right or left.

***Don't*** use `\w` and `\r` generally in your document.

In order to pretend the diagram isn't really as wide as the line, I added some negative spacing.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mbox{\hspace*{-2em}%
  \footnotesize % reduce the font size
  $
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \newcommand{\?}{\hspace*{\fill}}% temporary command
  \newcommand{\w}[1][]{\mathbf{w}_{j#1}}% temporary command
  \renewcommand{\r}[1][]{\mathbf{r}_{j#1}}% temporary command
  \begin{array}{ *{9}{ c >{{}}c<{{}} } l }
  \?\w[-4] &+& B\w[-3] &+& C\w[-2] &+& B\w[-1] &+& \w[]\? && && && && &=& \r[-2] \\
  %
  && \?\w[-3] &+& B\w[-2] &+& C\w[-1] &+& B\w[] &+& \w[+1]\? && && && &=& \r[-1] \\
  %
  && && \?\w[-2] &+& B\w[-1] &+& C\w[] &+& B\w[+1] &+& \w[+2]\? && && &=& \r[] \\
  %
  && && && \?\w[-1] &+& B\w[] &+& C\w[+1] &+& B\w[+2] &+& \w[+3]\? && &=& \r[+1] \\
  %
  && && && && \?\w[] &+& B\w[+1] &+& C\w[+2] &+& B\w[+3] &+& \w[+4]\?&=& \r[+2] \\
  \end{array}
$\hspace*{-2em}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You might perhaps go with `\small` instead of `\footnotesize`, depending on the line width in your document.

First try without the two `\hspace*{-2em}` to see whether it really fits.

[image]